# Add PHP variable in title of page

Tags: php

I have this name of product:

```
 ".$product -> name."
```

and this title:

```
$head["title"] = "same title text here";
```

How can i add name of product in title? Thanks.
I already tried transformations and rearrangements, googling and etc.

Comment: `$head["title"] = $product->name;`

Comment: Is the php code and the html code on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is on the same file try this:

```
<?php $head["title"] = $product->name; ?>

<title><?php echo $head['title']; ?></title>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
$title = $product -> name;
```

in html

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

Comment: Did youread the question! Would it be useful to use the questioners own variable names to make things clear?

Comment: if name of good in example is "Roses red" i want to print "Roses red" in title.

Comment: how are you getting product name??

Comment: its parsed from digiseller.ru .

Comment: <div class=\"poster\">
      <span class=\"name\"><a href=\"#\">".$product -> name."</a></span>
      <img src=\"http://graph.digiseller.ru/img.ashx?id_d=".$answer -> product -> id."&amp;\" width=\"346\" height=\"121\" alt=\"\">
     </div>